# How to rename an existing file

Tags: java, file, struts, rename

I have an existing file in my HDD and I want rename this file.

Comment: Rename it ... on the command line?  in Java?  What have you attempted to do?  How do you have a handle on the file?

Comment: hello, i have an existing file in my HDD and i want rename this file. i have looking for the renameTo function but Do I have to erase my file and recreates?

Comment: Make sure you add more information while posting a question, it saves both of our time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this:

```
new File(path).renameTo(new File(newPath));
```

Answer (score 2):

You may look at [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) [FileUtils.moveFile](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29). That method tries [`File.renameTo`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29), and if that fails, tries to copy&delete the file (e.g. when moving from one drive to another).

If you use `File.renameTo` directly (which should suffice if you only want to rename a file in the same directory), make sure you evaluate the returned boolean value!