# How to rename an existing file?

Tags: java, android, file

I have 2 files , `File src = new File("loc/xyz.mp3")` and `File dst=new File("loc/xyz1.mp3")`
Now , I want to rename `dst` to xyz.mp3 while delete `src` file. How can I accomplish this ?
I was trying ,

```
src.delete();
dst.renameTo(src);
```

I am running this in AsyncTask in background in my app , when I execute it first time , it works perfectly , however second time , it crashes. Please help how should I go about this.

Comment: Please share your logcat trace messages when it crashes. Did renameTo() return false or throw an exception?

Comment: Well , now it doesnt crash , infact it just deletes the first file now .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try doing:

```
new File("loc/xyz1.mp3").renameTo(new File("loc/xyz.mp3"));
```

This should automatically overwrite the original file. This answer was taken from here: [How to rename an existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804105/how-to-rename-an-existing-file?rq=1)

Comment: That does it quick and short!

Answer (score 2):

You should rename a file using `Files`, it works a lot more reliable than `renameTo()`.

```
Path source = currentFile.toPath();
try {
     Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling(formattedName));
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

Answer (score 2):

Docs says:

> Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname.
>
> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>       platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>       file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
>       might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>       already exists.  The return value should always be checked to make sure
>       that the rename operation was successful.

In `AsyncTask`, you can not guarantee the `src` and `dst` ,as @Machinarius said, check `src.exists() && dst.exists()` maybe avoid you error. Use `deleteOnExit` also a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

In the second run `dst` does not exist in the file system, you should throw a `if (src.exists() && dst.exists())` check into your code so as to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

Those two delete() and renameTo() will return true or false depending on it's execution result. Probably you need to add condition check if previous step was success and file is actually existing in the give path.