# Remove certain characters from a directory's name in Java

Tags: java

So I wrote a little program to use on a Unix machine that has to get all the names of the files and folders in a directory where it is stored and then remove all the characters from them. These characters (or a character) will be defined by a user. Use case: I put the program in the directory containing various useless files and directories named, for example, "NaCl2!!!!!!!!!", "H2O!", "O2" and "Lithium!!!!!" and I "ask" it to get rid of all the bangs in all the directores' names so it will result in this:

```
ls 
NaCl2 H2O O2 Lithium Unreal3.zip
```

Ok I guess you get it. So here's the code and it doesn't compile (

```
DirRename.java:18: error: method renameTo in class File cannot be applied to given types;
                tempDir.renameTo(name);
```

). I guess this error is caused with a substantial problem in my code. Is there a way to get it working, can you tell me, please?

```
import java.io.*; import java.util.Scanner;
class DirRename {
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        //DECLARING
        String name, curDir, annoyngChar;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //WORKING
        curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File dir = new File(curDir);
        File[] listOfFiles = dir.listFiles();
        System.out.print("Type a character (or a line of them) that you want to remove from directories' names:");
        annoyngChar = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nAll directories will get rid of " + annoyngChar + " in their names.");
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory() ) {
                File tempDir = listOfFiles[i];
                name = tempDir.getName().replaceAll(annoyngChar, "");
                tempDir.renameTo(name);
            }
        }                     
    }
}
```

Need to say, the program is unfinished, I am sorry for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename an existing file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970110/how-to-rename-an-existing-file)

Comment: Not actualy, since I don't just want to rename a file, I want the program to find all the directories that have to be renamed (they should contain the character or a line that I type when the program asks me to), and rename them by just deleting all the "illegal" characters (mentioned in the bracked above).

Comment: Change `tempDir.renameTo(name);` to `System.println("name=" + name)` to confirm the new name is right and then RTFM for `File.renameTo()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[File.renameTo(File dest)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) takes a `File` parameter, not a `String`. So, you need to create a `File` instance with the correct path (using the new name), and pass that instance to `renameTo`.

Try this (not tested):

```
import java.io.*; import java.util.Scanner;
class DirRename {
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        //DECLARING
        String name, curDir, annoyngChar;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //WORKING
        curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File dir = new File(curDir);
        File[] listOfFiles = dir.listFiles();
        System.out.print("Type a character (or a line of them) that you want to remove from directories' names:");
        annoyngChar = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nAll directories will get rid of " + annoyngChar + " in their names.");
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory() ) {
                File f = listOfFiles[i];
                String oldName = f.getName();
                name = oldName.replaceAll(annoyngChar, "");
                if (!oldName.equals(name)) {
                    File newF = new File(dir, name);
                    f.renameTo(newF);
                }
            }
        }                     
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [Files.move](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) to rename the file. The documentation has an example of how to rename a file while keeping it in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you a lot @cybersam !!!! It worked, I'll be trying to make it more lightweight later. Honestly, never thought anybody would help me because my questions kinda looks like [How to rename an existing file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970110/how-to-rename-an-existing-file)