# Media File Gets Corrupted after Renaming programmatically

Tags: android, mp3, file-rename, android-file, android-mediarecorder

I am renaming "temp-record.mp3" file programmatically after recording it through [OmRecorder](https://github.com/kailash09dabhi/OmRecorder), After recording and before renaming the file, MP3 file seems to play fine and works.
But after Renaming **"temp-record.mp3"** file to something dynamic **"userId-record-systime.mp3"** it gets **corrupted and DOES NOT PLAY**.

I'm using the following function to rename:

```
public static boolean renameFile(String fromFilePathWithExt,String toFilePathWithExt){
        LogUtils.d("from: "+fromFilePathWithExt);
        LogUtils.d("to: "+toFilePathWithExt);
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if(dir.exists()){
            File from = new File(fromFilePathWithExt);
            File to = new File(toFilePathWithExt);
            if(from.exists()) {
                return from.renameTo(to);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I've also notified about this [issues in Omrecorder](https://github.com/kailash09dabhi/OmRecorder/issues/48) repo, but I am still confused that Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Try doing:**

> new File("loc/xyz1.mp3").renameTo(new File("loc/xyz.mp3"));

This should automatically overwrite the original file. This answer was taken from here:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804105/how-to-rename-an-existing-file?rq=1)

Comment: Ok...Let me check more efficiently.